# How to create a custom extractor in SAP R/3 system?

Tags: sap-erp, sap-bw, sap-r3

I have to create a custom extractor in SAP R/3 system.

What are the ways to extract the data from required tables like `COVP`, `COEP`, `EKKN`, etc.?

Comment: Extract it into which kind of target system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you are asking to extract to SAP BI, although it seems you are probably lacking a bit in experience you'll have to ask an ABAPer to help you with some of this.

First you need to build a view on the DB table you want: go to transaction SE11 and select View, and give it a name. Usually I like to do ZBW_*tablename* and a Description such as BW Extractor View for Table *tablename*

Select all the fields from tge database table and activate.

Then go to transaction RSO2 and in this case you are dealing with Transactional tables.
Create a transactional extrator by entering a name Z_*tablename*_TRANS. Click CREATE.

On the next screen, select the position for your extractor in the application component hierarchy. When you replicate into SAP BI you will see your extractor in this position in the hierarchy, so it's important you remember where you put it.

Add the descriptions, and the Viewname that you just created. Select save.

That's it.

Answer (score 1):

in addition you can also create an extractor using a function module and an underlying structure. For that, select FM in RSO2 after you create your generic extractor and provide your structure and function module.

You can create the structure in SE11 and the function module in SE80. You need to know ABAP here but it's an extremely powerful approach to extracting data provided you don't need something simpler.

Comment: This is not as straightforward as it seems, because you have to handle the packetization of data in the function module, whereas the answer I gave requires no such knowledge. Indeed this approach should only be attempted by a very experienced ABAPer who knows how to write very high performance code. I rarely come across these people in SAP BI - present company notwithstanding.

Comment: Absolutely agreed. The original question was about the options to create an extractor - not about the pros and cons of each.

Answer (score 0):

first you will create the view on using se11 given the name and create now given the condition to the condition field and given the what are the fields you want in view field now you  go to rso2 and create what type of the data source you needed and given they application component name  for  the reason of where your data source shown now select the view and save the extract structure will be automatically created